# Can't get JavaFX running

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I got an important exam in the following days and need to set up JavaFX in Eclipse for that. I tried some basic code just to see if its running and I always get this error message:

> Exception in Application constructor Exception in thread "main"
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
> java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application
> instance: class pk.klausur.ui.KlausurverwaltungUI     at
> javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:891)
> at
> javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) Caused by:
> java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class
> com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl (in module javafx.graphics)
> cannot access class pk.klausur.ui.KlausurverwaltungUI (in module test)
> because module test does not export pk.klausur.ui to module
> javafx.graphics   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:361)
> at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:591)
> at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
> at
> javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:803)
> at
> javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
> at
> javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
> Method)   at
> javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
> at
> javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)

And this is the code to this message:

```
package pk.klausur.ui;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import pk.klausur.Klausurverwaltung;
import pk.klausur.Klausur;
import pk.klausur.Bewertung;
public class KlausurverwaltungUI extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        Klausurverwaltung verwaltung = new Klausurverwaltung();

        ComboBox <Klausur> Klausure = new ComboBox<Klausur>();

        VBox root = new VBox();

        ListView <Bewertung> bewertunge = new ListView<Bewertung>();

        GridPane gp = new GridPane();

        Button b1 = new Button("Klausuren");

        Label l1 = new Label("test");

        l1.setFont(new Font(50));

        Scene scene = new Scene(l1);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Would be awesome if someone could help and save my exam!

Comment: Format stack traces as code, they are easier to read that way.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using idea, I would recommend that you create a new javafx project using that and to verify if it works in your environment or not.
Clearly I can tell you that something wrong in the setup ..  Start with an example that's guaranteed to work like I mentioned (see f.i. stackoverflow.com/questions/52467561/…),

Comment: If using IntelliJ, see [this guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html) to creating a new project.

Comment: The question refers to eclipse, though this is a good answer if Idea can be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

The important line between all the exceptions is

```
module test does not export pk.klausur.ui to module javafx.graphics
```

which you would have to fix in your module-info.java file.

Something like:

```
module test {
    ...
    export pk.klausur.ui to javafx.graphics;
    ...
}
```